# Does not generate data in bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, fetch

I want to display some data in the bootstrap thumbnail. I dont get it why it does not show any data fetched from the database. database connection is correct.

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
 <div class="container">
  <center>
  <h1> Welkom!</h1>
   <p>Op de website van Ter Bruggen Antiek en Curiosa.<br />Voor uw mooiste antieke kroonluchters, lampen, meubelen en overige producten.</p>
   <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled" href="?page=info" role="button">Meer weten?</a></p>
  </center>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <center>
  <h2>Uitgelicht!</h2>
 </center>
  <div class="row">
   <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM advertentie, categorie WHERE advertentie.categorie_id = categorie.categorie_id AND uitgelicht=1";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
     while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
      echo   "<div class='col-lg-3'>";
      echo     "<div class='thumbnail'";
      echo     "<img class='img-square img-responsive' src='../img/uploads/".$row['filename']."'/> ";
      echo      "<div class='caption'>";
      echo    "<h4>".$row['advertentietitel']."</h4>";
      echo    "<p>".$row['categorie_naam']."</p>";
      echo    "<p>".$row['verkooprijs']."</p>";
      echo    "<p><a href='?page=details&id=".$row['advertentie_id']." class='btn btn-primary'>Bekijk</a></p>";
      echo   "</div>";
      echo   "</div>";
      echo   "</div>";
     }
    }
   ?>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It is not the '>' after the 'thumbnail div'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select query is not correct. You should use JOIN of mysql. I don't know your database structure. If you show your database structure then I could help you. Please try below query and share the results

```
$sql = "SELECT advertentie.* FROM advertentie LEFT OUTER JOIN categorie on  advertentie.categorie_id = categorie.categorie_id WHERE advertentie.uitgelicht=1";
```

Comment: it showed the data but all of it. the statement 'AND uitgelicht=1' (is in the advertentie table) is not working.